# Can invoking dawRect: on background thread cause crash?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, crash, drawrect

I have some heavy UI drawing operations so I passed it to a background thread. Around 100% of my reported crashes occured during this operation. There were no such problems when the drawing ran on the main thread, the code just unchaged.

Any risk of drawing in the background?

(I'm populating UIScrollView contents, could be the problem there?)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you are not supposed to call `drawRect:` yourself, UIKit does that for you. You are supposed to call `setNeedsDisplay`. Second, UIKit is not thread-safe so calling any UIKit drawing operations on any thread other than the main thread can crash your app, as you've experienced.

However, CoreGraphics is thread-safe if you create the context to draw in yourself and then only use CoreGraphics calls. So what you can do is to do your time consuming drawing in a background thread with CoreGraphics, where you draw into an image context and store the image in an instance variable. Then call `setNeedsDisplay` on the main thread and simply display the rendered image in your `drawRect:` method.

So in pseudo-code (Core Graphics version):

```
- (void)redraw
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(redrawInBackground) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)redrawInBackground
{
    CGImageRef image;
    CGContextRef context;

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(..., self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height, ...);

    // Do the drawing here

    image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    // This must be an atomic property.
    self.renderedImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image]];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGRelease(image);

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.renderedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
}
```

The UIKit version would be:

```
- (void)redrawInBackground
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

    // Do the drawing here.

    self.renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: [What's New in iOS: iOS 4.0: UIKit Framework Enhancements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29): “Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe.”

Comment: Passing a graphics context provided by UIKit across threads is still unsafe though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I missed that.

Comment: Thank, I'm not calling drawRect: myself, but do heavylifting there.

Comment: I'll do everything on the main thread regarding to UIKit calls, the only thing I can pass to background (if I understood you) to do custom drawing in separated contexts, then pass the result UIImage to the main thread (a.k.a populate UIKit elemets).

Comment: Please confirm if this approach seems thread safe, and thanks again.

Comment: See my edited answer, I've added pseudo-code to illustrate the method I'm describing.

Comment: is `setNeedsDisplay` thread-safe? you are calling it in background thread

Comment: @xlc0212 You're right, I've fixed the code. In my experience, both on Mac and iOS it's not a problem to call `setNeedsDisplay`/`setNeedsDisplay:` on another thread... it simply doesn't do anything (that is, the view is _not_ redrawn).